# Regex to find text outside square brackets, in posts formatted [H] Text 1 [W] Text 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm looking for a way to capture 2 groups of text, a "have" part (written after `[H]`), and a "want" part (written after `[W]`).

Sample title: `[H] $10 [W] 100 credits`

I'm interested in grabbing `$10` and `100 credits` into separate variables.

So far I've only worked out the following regex:

`^(.*\](.*)\[.*)$`

and this gives me a group for the first part, but I'm not sure how to adapt this to capture the second group as well.

Thanks!

Comment: You could also make the match a bit more specific `\[H] (.+?) \[W] (.+)` https://regex101.com/r/ltcJUB/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match `[H]` and capture in group 1 as least amount of characters. Then match `[W]` and capture the rest of the characters in group 2.

```
\[H] (.+?) \[W] (.+)
```

**Explanation**

- `\[H]`  Match `[H]` and a single space
- `(.+?)`  Capture **group 1**, match 1+ times any char except a newline non greedy
- `\[W]`  Match `[W]` and a single space
- `(.+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ times any char except a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ltcJUB/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/GEaDbp)

```
import re

regex = r"\[H] (.+?) \[W] (.+)"
test_str = "[H] $10 [W] 100 credits"

matches = re.search(regex, test_str)
if matches:
    variable1 = matches.group(1)
    variable2 = matches.group(2)

    print(variable1)
    print(variable2)
```

Output

```
$10
100 credits
```

Or to match 1 or more spaces except a newline after the char in square brackets:

```
\[H][^\S\r\n]+(.+?)[^\S\r\n]+\[W][^\S\r\n]+(.+)
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yh2P7P/1)

Comment: The broken-down explanation helped - thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider capturing a `H` or `W` inside brackets and then match any chars other than brackets and digits up to the first digit, and capture that number.

The regex may look like

```py
\[([HW])][^][\d]*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A4oJzY/1). To match anything inside square brackets, replace `[HW]` with `[^][]+`.

**Regex details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([HW])` - Group 1: `H` or `W`
- `]` - a `]` char
- `[^][\d]*` - zero or more chars other than `[`, `]`, and digits
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 2: one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/l60yHE):

```py
import re
text = "[H] $10 [W] 100 credits"
print( dict(re.findall(r'\[([HW])][^][\d]*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', text)) )
# => {'H': '10', 'W': '100'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try a specific regex `\[H\] +([^ ]+) +\[W\] +(.+)`

With:

- `\[H\] ?`: the `[H]` followed by one or unlimited spaces
- `([^ ]+)`: the first needed group (everything excepted a space)
- `+\[W\] +`: followed by one or unlimited spaces, then the `[W]`, then one or unlimited spaces
- `(.+)`: the last needed pattern

https://regex101.com/r/hryuRc/3